# Why Is There No Woman In Observers Future?

Tags: fringe

In one of recent episode of Fringe, We have seen that Observers not being born, just "manufactured". But it is not clarify that why there is no woman in the future, women could be also "manufactured". There must be intentinally choice causing that, and indeed that was more important subject than manifacturing, But what happened to women?? is there any good explanation?

Comment: Looks similar but very different as well, they were talking about only males, not females, just try to find any word of "woman", or "female" etc

Comment: discussion of why there are only males is the same thing as discussing why there are no females. Your question merely has a slight different emphasis.

Comment: Infact two questions are complete each other; They discussed about why they are white male, but not asking what happened to women. You cant distroy a gender without question, or reaction. This is what I am interesting in; there was never any sign for that reaction in Fringe. Screenwriters like to create mysteries, but never leave an answer, or any key which we can grab an explanation from. Sorry for my english, I am trying to state my opinion with my poor english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would be the point of having women?

All of the reproductive organs/processes would be completely useless if you aren't actually going to have babies. So if you are going to pick a gender to manufacture, one should manufacture the one with less "reproductive machinery" and that would seem to be males.

Comment: I am not agree, but this would be possible truth for observers future. I have never seen any sign about this issue on any episode of Fringe, "ignored"

Comment: How do we know observers are even male? They are manufactured.

Comment: @SimonO'Doherty, you could certainly argue that they are asexual. That raises the question of whether they can't have sex or just don't. But they appear male which suggests that they were cloned from the last generation of natural male humans.

Comment: I think they are obviously white males, which also refering a futher futher result of paternalistic world. Because females would be observers perfectly, why not? But then approach of Observers would look unsharp. I think this is only just another unconsidered detail of Fringe narrative.

Comment: @Digerkam, Females grow breasts, a uterus, have periods, etc. From the observers perspective all of these things are useless wastes of resources. Hence, I think they would see females as subpar observers.

Comment: All those are not even a reason to explain lack of females. It is still a unconsidered detail for me in Fringe narrative.

Comment: @Digerkam, why aren't those reasons? You are rejecting my explanation without giving a reason.

Comment: So that means they have no penis? if breasts was a problem, then they would have to get rid of it; evolution is evolution! Breasts are no problem for women. Uterus? How does uterus limit inteligence? Period? They can stop period easily, because todays medicine can stop period if woman wants, even start period again whenever woman want. I hope I explain my reasons somehow with my poor english ;)

Comment: @Digerkam, of course the uterus doesn't limit intelligence. But it does take up some of the nutrition the body receive. Same with breasts. Of course, you could just remove the breasts/uterus, and eliminate the period. But from the purely logical perspective of the observers, why do all that when you can just start with men? Men just would seem to have less stuff to remove. (For all we know, they did eliminate the penis.)